# flink application is halted after consuming messages from kafka

Tags: apache-flink

i am using Flink Connector Kafka 1.8.0. (depends on kafka-clients 2.0.1)
after processing several messages from kafka i get those errors, and thatn applicating is halted

```
•   2019-12-26 06:37:39,843 INFO 
org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction - FlinkKafkaProducer 3/4 - 
checkpoint 266 complete, committing transaction TransactionHolder{handle=KafkaTransactionState 
[transactionalId=null, producerId=-1, epoch=-1], transactionStartTime=1577341934732} from checkpoint 
266
•   2019-12-26 06:42:39,043 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer 
clientId=consumer-22, groupId=com.citi.gsp.onepx.raw_positions] Node 1001 was unable to process the 
fetch request with (sessionId=965915581, epoch=1603): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
```

can you assist?

Comment: What do You meant by halted ?? Does the job go to `ERROR` state ? The logs You have provided shouldn't in general cause the failure of the job, most probably there should be some errors in log.